# Anybody know what this ui component is called?

Tags: android, user-interface, locking, components

I tried to look up the ui tool that is present on my droid x phone but cannot anything on it. 
My look screen looks like https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCALN.jpg. Anyone know what the name is for the android ui component that helps you from the lock to any of the components(phone, unlock, text,etc)?

Comment: I guess that is a custom view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a **Native UI Component**. 
This is actually a **widget**. We can call it a "**Lock Widget**".
There are many similar widgets in Google Play.